# Change Eclipse tab to correctly indent line as Emacs does

Tags: eclipse

In Emacs when I hit tab anywhere on a line, the line will indent correctly (or at least to the mode settings). When I hit tab again it will move back to the next block. When programming Python this really helps since closing a block is done by lowering the indention level.

Is there a way to configure Eclipse to do the same?

Currently, I have to erase the leading white space then hit tab.

This question is a reposting of [a superuser question.](https://superuser.com/questions/223130/change-eclipse-tab-to-correctly-indent-line-as-emacs-does)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try ctrl-i (Cmd-i on osx) to indent the current line or a selection inside eclipse (if you're using default key binds as opposed to emacs). Or, if you want a different key bind, go to Appearances > General > Keys and change the bind for `Correct Indentation` to key(s) of your choice

Comment: This works for java, but unfortunately not in the python module.  I guess I can go bug their list.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, go to Windows -> Preference -> Java -> Formatter.

In Active Profile drop down box, select any profile, click Edit on right of it.

In Profile Dialog box opened, you can change a lot of things like Indentation, New Line, Braces, White Spaces etc.

Alternatively, if your profile is altogether different than standard one, Create a new active profile and then edit it accordingly.

Comment: This will change the indention rules, but I still have to delete the leading white space for tab to automatically indent correctly.

Comment: This does not change tab key behaviour.