# Changing indent on nextline after left bracket in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Often times my code does not fit on the same line, I want to place them on the next line to increase readability, but everytime eclipse always create incorrect indent. Is there a way I can ask eclipse to indent properly?

[image]

I tried the solution on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490569/change-eclipse-tab-to-correctly-indent-line-as-emacs-does), but it does not seems to do anything for me.

Comment: I think this is to avoid confusion. For example, to show the difference between an `if` condition's second line and the if-ed block itself.

Comment: @マルちゃんだよ I see.. but almost 90% of my code involves going to the next line, I wonder if I can find a way to change the behavior.

Comment: The second answer in that question should help you with what you're looking for, I've used it before to bypass default formatting.

Comment: You could always press shift+tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can specify properties such as this in the preferences of the IDE, your indentation preferences are not recommended.  The eclipse identations are proper.

Single identations, as you would like, are used to denote the opening of blocks of code such as the following (Curly braces):

```
if (i = 1) {
    //Single identation here
}
```

Double identation is used for situations such as the following (parenthesis):

```
System.out.println("This is some string that"
        + " I want to continue on the next line");
```

In conclusion, you can change it, but Eclipse is actually doing it right to avoid confusion between the two.

Comment: I am just trying make my life a little easier, when following the college text book...

Comment: Your life will be made easier by following the standard, and just dealing with the difference between the two at present moment.